# ADODB.Recordset Error reading from XML (ADODB.Stream)

Tags: xml, vb6, adodb, recordset

I will start with the scenario:

1. I have a vb 6 application that will get data from a web service and manage that data using a ADODB.Recordset
2. In order to accomplish that i created a DLL that connect to the web service and create an xml in the following format (retrieved from MSDN support):

   ```
   <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
   xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
   xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
   xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
   <s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'><s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
           <s:AttributeType name='Column1' rs:number='0'>
               <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='4294967295' rs:long='true'/>
           </s:AttributeType>
           <s:AttributeType name='Column2' rs:number='1'>
               <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='4294967295' rs:long='true'/>
           </s:AttributeType><s:AttributeType name='Column3' rs:number='2'>
               <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='4294967295' rs:long='true'/>
           </s:AttributeType>
    </s:Schema>
   <rs:data>
   <z:row Column1 = "ABC" Column2 = "DEF" Column3 = "GHI"/>
   <z:row Column1 = "JKL" Column2 = "MNO" Column3 = "PQR"/>
   </rs:data>
   </xml>
   ```

This xml is returned to VB 6 as a string and I am using the following snippet to convert this into an ADODB.Recordset object:

```
    Dim RS As ADODB.Stream
    Set RS = New ADODB.Stream
    RS.Open
    RS.WriteText XML 'This have the XML string 

    RS.Position = 0

    Dim recset As ADODB.Recordset
    Set recset = New ADODB.Recordset

    recset.Open RS

    RS.Close
    Set RS = Nothing
```

Now, this executing well but when I try to use Column1 I am getting a run time error about some missing columns. When i check the recordset a convert it to an XML to compare i get this:

```
   <xml xmlns:s='uuid:BDC6E3F0-6DA3-11d1-A2A3-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:dt='uuid:C2F41010-65B3-11d1-A29F-00AA00C14882'
    xmlns:rs='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:rowset'
    xmlns:z='#RowsetSchema'>
    <s:Schema id='RowsetSchema'><s:ElementType name='row' content='eltOnly' rs:updatable='true'>
            <s:AttributeType name='Column2' rs:number='1'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='4294967295' rs:long='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType><s:AttributeType name='Column3' rs:number='2'>
                <s:datatype dt:type='string' dt:maxLength='4294967295' rs:long='true'/>
            </s:AttributeType>
     </s:Schema>
     <rs:data>
     <z:row Column2 = "ABC" Column3 = "DEF"/>
     <z:row Column2 = "JKL" Column3 = "MNO"/>
     </rs:data>
     </xml>
```

For some reason it is removing the first column from the xml but taking it value and using it for the remaining columns. I tried to add a dummy column but it did not work. I added an ID column but it did not work.

Any ideas on why is this happening? This recordset is used to fill data gridviews. Is there any VB 6 object equivalent to an ADO Recordset that I could use to load the data from the XML string?